# trigger to Send mail when inserted record as PDF file

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Am trying to create trigger base to send email for each user on every record created/inserted in my table, since i have already the path in the DB
below my code, please if anyone could help me on this

```
CREATE TRIGGER DP_READY
   ON  dbo.TimesheetLog
   for insert
AS 
    declare @pdf nvarchar (max)
declare @email nvarchar (50)
declare @fcode nvarchar (50)
declare @date date 
    set @pdf=  (select distinct  'C:\Papyrus_Router\Output\PDF' +  '\' + a.cpdffilename AS pdf_f , b.Name,b.cforeman,  b.Email
  from timesheetlog as a left join EmailSubscription b on right(ltrim(rtrim(a.cheaderkey)) ,6)= b.cforeman
   where cstatus = 'DP-READY')

   set @email= (select distinct    b.Email
    from timesheetlog as a left join EmailSubscription b on right(ltrim(rtrim(a.cheaderkey)) ,6)= b.cforeman
    where cstatus = 'DP-READY')

    set @fcode =   (select distinct  b.cforeman +'-'+ b.Name+'-'+ convert(varchar(50),convert(date,a.dcreated))
  from timesheetlog as a left join EmailSubscription b on right(ltrim(rtrim(a.cheaderkey)) ,6)= b.cforeman
   where cstatus = 'DP-READY')  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
set @date = (select distinct  convert(date,a.dcreated)
  from timesheetlog as a left join EmailSubscription b on right(ltrim(rtrim(a.cheaderkey)) ,6)= b.cforeman
   where cstatus = 'DP-READY')
   -- Insert statements for trigger here
    if CHARINDEX(@pdf, @email) > 0 and @date = getdate()
BEGIN
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients=@email,
    @file_attachments = @pdf,
    @subject = @fcode,
    @body = 'Your Sync data from the Pens '

END
GO
```

am getting this error

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Comment: set your variables like:

select @pdf='C:\Papyrus_Router\Output\PDF' +  '\' + a.cpdffilename 
  from timesheetlog as a left join EmailSubscription b on right(ltrim(rtrim(a.cheaderkey)) ,6)= b.cforeman
   where cstatus = 'DP-READY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign multiple values into a variable:

```
set @pdf=  (
  select distinct  'C:\Papyrus_Router\Output\PDF' +  '\' + a.cpdffilename AS pdf_f, 
  b.Name,
  b.cforeman,  
  b.Email
```

The problem is Name, cforeman and Email.

Also, your trigger doesn't use the virtual table `inserted` at all, so it's probably not working as you expect.

Comment: thanks its worked, i didn't get what you mean for virtual value, am trying to insert new record in my table timesheetlog nothing happen?? @jamesZ

Answer (score 0):

Change your trigger with following code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DP_READY
ON  dbo.TimesheetLog
for insert
AS 
   declare @pdf nvarchar (max)
   declare @email nvarchar (50)
   declare @fcode nvarchar (50)
   declare @date date 

  select @pdf='C:\Papyrus_Router\Output\PDF' +  '\' + a.cpdffilename,
  @fcode=b.cforeman +'-'+ b.Name+'-'+ convert(varchar(50),convert(date,a.dcreated)),
  @email=b.Email,
  @date=convert(date,a.dcreated)
  from timesheetlog as a left join EmailSubscription b 
  on right(ltrim(rtrim(a.cheaderkey)) ,6)= b.cforeman
  where cstatus = 'DP-READY'

BEGIN
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients=@email,
@file_attachments = @pdf,
@subject = @fcode,
@body = 'Your Sync data from the Pens '

END
GO
```

Comment: how i can get the last inserted or updated record as always @Sundar Singh

Comment: you can get your columns from inserted result set.
SELECT * FROM INSERTED.